# Seeking in an mp3 file

Tags: java, audio, audio-player

I'm working on mp3 player using java by reading the file, decoding frames and playback audio. However, I want to support my app with seeking. For CBR its easy because I can approximately calculate how much bytes I should skip. For example: seeking 50s with 128 kbps it's approximately `(50/0.026)*417`. But that doesn't work with VBR because bitrate is not constant.

Is there any way or method to calculate how many bytes I should skip in VBR without decoding all the frames in the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by calculating the average bitrate for VBR files.
That can be done by dividing the file length in bits on the song duration.
`avg = size*8/duration` then seek as CBR but with calculating the frame size with the average bitrate instead of constant bitrate.

Answer (score 0):

You might decode the mp3 file into a buffer, and do your playback from the buffer area (counting frames as you go).

Comment: Provided there's enough available memory for the buffer. This is true of individual songs on modern computers, not so much of podcasts on low-end smartphones.

Comment: And the question was about how to seek accurately to timestamps within that stream.